# Having trouble streaming music over my WLAN through iTunes and Apple TV

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, itunes, latency, appletv

My wife recently purchased me Apple TV for Xmas and I am trying to set it up so it can access my music over a wireless network and I am experiencing network latency issues when trying to stream music through Apple TV from an external hard drive.  Here is a quick summary of my wireless LAN configuration:

My iTunes library is managed through my desktop computer.  My desktop is connected to the network and internet via a wireless connection using the D-Link DWA-552 XtremeN Desktop Adapter.  I am using the Netgear WNDR4000 as my network router.  I have recently moved by iTunes content from my desktop hard drive to external hard drive directly connected to the router.  I can access my content using iTunes on my desktop without any issues.  When I try to access my content through Apple TV is where I have network latency issues.

Apple TV does see my iTunes library content but when I try to play a song through Apple TV it sits on the loading screen and does nothing.  The most frustrating part it is that is inconsistent.  It will sometimes stream the content, but it will randomly stop.

It shows 130.0 Mbps speed and four out of five bars for the signal quality for the D-Link card when I view the wireless connection status through the Network and Sharing Center application on Windows 7.

So my question is, what is the best to determine where the bottleneck in this whole process?  Do you think my network card might be the culprit that is causing the network latency when it is used as a go between for another devices on the network?  Is there a way to monitor traffic on my network between all my devices?  Is there a way to configure Apple TV to access the iTunes library directly on the external hard drive without going through my desktop itunes?

Comment: Verify what you did against [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH974?viewlocale=en_US) and post the result.

Comment: Yes I have verified all of those items in the article you provided.

Comment: Let me know if this [Post](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=71641) helps. Try test your wireless with 2.4GHz only.

Comment: Make sure you eliminate the external hard drive as a culprit first. Move your iTunes library (or part of it) back to your PC, and see how well it plays on Apple TV. I can't help you for the rest, but this sounds like a good starting point to me.

Comment: The more you segment the location of the files, the more it takes for them to be processed and reach the AppleTV in higher quality/speed. keep them on a internal hard drive if possible.

Comment: @John Siu - I have turned off the wireless broadcast for my 5 GHz signal and only connected to might 2.4 GHz and the results are inconsistent.  I was able to connect right from the start then it could not stream music after a couple of minutes.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn - My hard drive on my computer is scheduled to be de-fragmentated every night.  I just ran Windows 7 Disk Defragmeter and it gave a 0% fragmented report.

Comment: @MichaelKniskern I think we need to narrow down the problem, weather it is originated from WiFi or storage or something else. Please connect the Apple TV to your router also. So both your network and Apple TV are using the wired network. And see if the latency problem occur.

Comment: as segmented i meant a physical location more far, needing to use more transferences for the information to reach the destination(your apple tv)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same router and had the same problem.  The fix for me was to do a site-survey and set my channels as far away from my neighbors as possible.

If you think latency is the cause, ping your appleTV from your desktop (or better yet your router) several hundred times and make sure the ping is **consistent**.  With wireless N it should be always under 30ms or so.  Even a **consistent** 200 ms latency should not interfere with streaming music.

Another thing you may want to check is that another device has a static IP set in your DCHP pool range.  This would create an annoying conflict that could cause this type of problem.

Comment: I pinged Apple TV from my desktop and it was showing a range of time between 2ms and 14 ms.  It did occasionally go over 30ms, but not for long periods of time.  How would I ping directly from my router?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running a lan cable or if you can't using a Powerline ethernet adapter thus fixing your problem. I don't think this wifi tech is all its cracked up to be. Very easy to become congested and interference is a real issue.